# Gitlab web interface - download snapshot size is ZERO

Tags: git, gitlab, snapshot

I've been using gitlab (on Debian Jessie, currently gitlab-ce 8.7.0-ce.0) for about a year now and I'm very happy with it. A colleague of mine asked me to download some code of mine, so I gave him access to my gitlab. For the first time the function "Download zip", which downloads a snapshot of the source code, was tried. We discovered that it gives a zip file with size that is exactly zero.

I tried other types, like tar.gz and tar, but these give a blank page and nothing happens.

Also I noticed that the file name is "archive.zip", and it is not something related to the project/branch/commit hash.

Could someone tell me whether this is a bug or a problem on my end and assist me in resolving this? Please feel free to ask for any additional information you require.

I would like to add that I previously had a problem that cloning from my gitlab https would give empty repositories. I resolved this issue using these lines in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
nginx['enabled'] = false
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8081"
```

Comment: Is it similar to this issue? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3262

Comment: This comment might help: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3262#note_2653202

Comment: @Jamesking56 Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: @Jamesking56 There's no clear thing to do in the comment you mentioned. However, I noticed that another comment that came after that uses the same additional lines in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. The lines are: `nginx['enabled'] = false
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8081"
`. Could this be related to the problem? I used these lines back then to solve a problem related to cloning empty repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Gitlab was upgraded and uses a new reverse proxy server of its own, called "Gitlab-workhorse" since a while. I had to reconfigure my [Apache webserver with a new virtual host](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache) script for the new reverse proxy. Also I had to modify the configuration of `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` from:

```
nginx['enabled'] = false
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8081"
```

to:

```
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8181"
```